# Fortran GUI: Can Dislin be used to create an event handling GUI?

Tags: user-interface, fortran

I have been searching for the easiest way to integrate a GUI into my Fortran programs.  So far Dislin has been the simplest to implement but it seems like it can only take some input and then pass those values to the rest of the code after the GUI closes.  I cannot figure out how to get a button to call a function.  Is this even possible with Dislin?

The idea is to have the user select a file or two, add some input and run the code.  I specifically want a button to open a file chooser window, the dwgfil subroutine in Dislin.

Comment: You could try gtk-fortran instead. There are some tutorials and demos included.

Comment: Maybe it is useful to ask the developer directly in the forum...? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dislin-users/pMIv-9aNrtE also http://www.star.le.ac.uk/~cgp/dislinGUI.html

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir , I also have a c/gtk program working.  I was thinking it may be simpler to write the interface in c/gtk and call my fortran program from that, or even from c# since I'm leaning toward Windows and the tools are really nice for WinAPI.  I'll have to give the gtk-fortran bindings a try, i'm just worried it may be buggy.

Comment: Thank you @roygvib , I did actually try those codes from star.le..., they work.  Those codes are one step behind where I want to be so I will look into the forum you posted.